# The postmark on letter from either KRISHNAGIRI or DHARMAPURI has only "RI" visible. What is the chance the letter came from KRISHNAGIRI?

Tags: combinatorics

> A letter is known to have come either from "KRISHNAGIRI" or "DHARMAPURI". On the post mark only the two consecutive letters "RI" are visible. Then the chance that it came from KRISHNAGIRI is ...

---

My solution:

In "KRISHNAGIRI" we have two RI

In "DHARMAPURI" we have one RI

Therefore, the probability it came from "KRISHNAGIRI" is 2/3.

But the answer is 9/14. I am not able to get this answer.

Comment: user438666's answer spells out how to do the question in detail, but what you are missing is that the two words are different lengths.

Comment: Actually the answer depends on the "blind" probability that the letter came from KRISHNAGIRI, $P(\text{K})$; in which case, the "blind" probability that the letter came from DHARMAPURI is $1-P(\text{K})$. Given the additional information that RI appears, we get an "informed" probability that the letter came from KRISHNAGIRI to be $P(\text{K}|\text{R})=\frac{18P(\text{K})}{8P(\text{K})+10}$. If $P(\text{K})=\frac12$, we get $P(\text{K}|\text{R})=\frac9{14}$.

Comment: It's not a good question: you have to guess the assumptions which the question setter used. But I don't think it's [tag:combinatorics]. I'm not sure how best to tag it: maybe [tag:probability] [tag:bayes-theorem].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall Bayes' theorem: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$

if $K$ stands for KRISHNAGIRI and $D$ for DHARMAPURI

$$P(K| \textrm{RI is on the letter})=\frac{P(\textrm{RI is on the letter}|K)P(K)}{P(\textrm{RI is on the letter})}=\frac{\frac{2}{10}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{10}}=\frac{90}{14}\frac{1}{10}=\frac{9}{14} $$

because

$$P(\textrm{RI is on the letter}|K)=2/10$$ as there are 10 pairs of consecutive letters in KRISHNAGIRI, 2 of which are RI, $P(K)=1/2$ as it could've come from either city and

$$P(\textrm{RI is on the letter})=P(K)P(\textrm{RI is on the letter}|K)+P(D)P(\textrm{RI is on the letter}|D) $$

and $P(\textrm{RI is on the letter}|D)=1/9$ by the same reasoning as before.

EDIT: as @Especially Lime says, what went wrong is that the two words are of different length, so the probability that the two characters RI survive knowing that all two consecutive characters have equal chance of surviving is different for the two cities, you can verify that if the words had the same length the probability would indeed be $2/3$

Comment: Why is $P(K)=P(D)=\frac12$? That seems to be missing from the information, but assumed given the answer.

Comment: @robjohn True, I assumed it since it wasn't specified as it seemed like the most reasonable option if you have no idea which city the letter came from.. also given the answer I assumed whoever wrote the problem meant this